# difficult in conjunctive adverb punctuation

Tags: grammar

Are the usage of 'for example' correct in the following?

However, it is hard to see a person can have a sound education and appropriate qualifications **;for example, a degree.**

However, it is hard to see a person can have a sound education and appropriate qualifications **a degree, for example.**

However, it is hard to see a person can have a sound education and appropriate qualifications. **For example, a degree.**

However, it is hard to see a person can have a sound education and appropriate qualifications, **for example, a degree.**

Comment: You want the last one for the example, but your sentence is ungrammatical. *See a person can* doesn't work. The *for* in *for example* is a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

As you have it written, you don't have a complete sentence. Ending your examples with a period is problematic. You have two options:

1) add the word **that**. Your example is not a case you can remove it and maintain the sentence's integrity.

*However, it is hard to see that a person can have a sound education and appropriate qualifications, for example, a degree.*

In this case, the degree has to satisfy both the education and the qualification piece.

2) You can **complete your thought**

*However, it is hard to see a person can have a sound education--for example, a degree--and appropriate qualifcations [when applying for a competitive job before the age of 25].*

I like using em-dashes to anchor my clause when the clause itself contains a comma. Also, it seems the degree is specific to education.